# Is scientific progress hindered by page limit and page format?

Tags: publications, research-process, peer-review, journals, academic-life

There is a trend in STEM: things get more and more complicated over time.

There seems to be two things that are not matching up with the pace of our time: page limit, and page format.

**Page limit**: for example, to me this is anti-interdisciplinary. As results concern more disciplines, it is necessary to introduce background of many disparate fields. But due to the page limit, how can one reasonable do this? A picture is worth a thousand words, but how can we fit these pictures into our publication if there is a tight page limit?

**Page format**: for example, suppose you have very long equation (that runs across an entire page) or very large amount of data, how is it we are suppose to fit them into, say, two columns?

Does anyone have similar concerns or have seen how publications deal with them?

Comment: Your data comment suggests it's common in your field to publish all your data in the paper?

Comment: This seems to be an invitation to a discussion rather than a precisely framed question.

Comment: Physical Review Letters has a page limit. Physical Review B does not. For a given article you choose the appropriate journal.

Comment: "suppose you have very long equation (that runs across an entire page)" Is it ever really necessary to an equation that long? I would argue that in such a case the onus for a clearer presentation is on you and not on the journal.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes.  In particular, page limits have caused many authors to design terrible figures that contain many tiny, unrelated graphs packed close together.  This makes scientific papers harder to understand.

Comment: In my area usually page limits do not involve figures, and are in fact often word count limits.

Comment: @ChristianHennig In physics there is usually a word limit and a formula for computing the number of "words" for each figure.

Answer (score 5):

You choose the appropriate journal for your research. In my experience, and field, journals with page limits are for rapid dissemination of results. The article would usually have deferred a lot of methodology to other papers or the put the details into a supplementary section which doesn't count towards page limits. More in depth and longer papers end up in different journals. If when writing a short paper I realize I need more space than is available I would just reconsider which journal to publish in.

At the same time, there is a skill to writing a short paper and sticking to the point. You have a message you want to convey to a reader so stick to it. Many papers I've read just keep going and going and really should of stopped at an earlier point.

You ask about the figures. Have you considered whether you need so many separate figures? Plots can often be consolidated and perhaps if you thought about your data differently you would need less figures. Or long equations? Either it's important to the paper so you include it, or it's not that important and you don't include it (perhaps just referencing another work where the equation is important).

Why put lots of data in a paper? Show a short summary and point to an online storage system (like Zenodo) which can store the data for you in machine readable formats. One of the most annoying things I find is people putting long tables in papers that a) serve no purpose to the narrative b) can't be easily copied from the final PDF. When I'm reading your paper I don't need to see the tables showing you did lots of work. I only need to see the tables if and when I'm reusing your work and that will occur at a different time to when I'm reading your paper. So don't make me have to skip over lots of data when it's not needed.

Comment: In addition, nobody has time to read lots of long papers. Scientific progress is probably greatly enhanced by enforcing page limits.

Comment: "page limits are for rapid dissemination of results" PRL has long claimed that, but if you look at the data it's actually a slower journal.

Comment: "Plots can often be consolidated"  Can be but it's not reader-friendly.

Comment: Hence the qualifier often not always. And this doesn't just mean stick all the curves on one plot just think about the data differently. Maybe you don't need to plot every curve, maybe there's some quantity that summarises the curve that could be plotted as a single point instead etc.